# If I use next_page_token, does it cost an additional response?

Tags: google-api, response, payment

Accessing Additional Results
By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages. If your search will return more than 20, then the search response will include an additional value — next_page_token. Pass the value of the next_page_token to the pagetoken parameter of a new search to see the next set of results. If the next_page_token is null, or is not returned, then there are no further results.

How is next_page_token paid? Or is it only charged for the first response from placeAPI? Or I will ask a question differently. If I use next_page_token after the first 20 spots, is it taken into account somewhere in the payment?

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question?